PyGame ошибка No file 'sto4.png' found in working directory
У меня ошибка в строке ниже. Там написано у меня (1,5) , файлов с навзанием sto у меня 4. Sto, sto1 и так до тройки. Помогите:
File "c:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\PY\Игра\игранастоящая.py", line 90, in <module>
    player = Player() #создать спрайт
             ^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\PY\Игра\игранастоящая.py", line 43, in __init__
    img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sto" + str(i) + ".png")).convert_alpha()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: No file 'sto4.png' found in working directory 'C:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\PY'.  





import pygame , os , sys

# Переменные
worldx = 800
worldy= 600
fps = 40 #частота кадров
ani = 4 #циклы анимации
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx,worldy])
BLUE = (25,25,200)
BLACK = (23,23,23)
WHITE = (254,254,254)
ALPHA = (0,255,0)

main = True

# Объекты
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #персонаж сам
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  # тут тоже надо 2 подчеркивания
        self.movex = 0 # перемещение по х
        self.movey = 0 # перемещение по у
        self.frame = 0 #подсчет кадров
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1,5):
         img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sto" + str(i) + ".png")).convert_alpha()
        img.convert_alpha()
        img.set_colorkey(ALPHA)

        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            

    def control(self,x,y):
        # Управление перемещением главного персонажа

        self.movex += x
        self.movey += y

    def update(self):
        #новая позиция спрайта

        self.rect.x = self.rect.x + self.movex
        self.rect.y = self.rect.y + self.movey

        # ВЛЕВО
        if self.movex < 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 *ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.images[self.frame//ani], True, False)

        # Вправо
        if self.movex > 0:
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame > 3 *ani:
                self.frame = 0
            self.image = self.images[self.frame//ani]        

        # img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('sto.png'))
        # self.images.append(img)
        # self.image = self.images[0]
        # self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

# Настройка

pygame.display.set_caption("Best Parkour Master | Tigran Gevorkyan")
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load("ико.png"))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx, worldy])
player = Player() #создать спрайт
player.rect.x = 0 #x
player.rect.y = 0 #y
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)
steps = 10 # пиксели для перемещения

# Скорость перемещения персонажа
speed = 5

# Цвет фона (если необходимо)
BACKGROUND_COLOR = (255, 255, 255)

# Загрузка изображений
background_image = pygame.image.load('фон1.png')



# Позиция спрайта
sprite_x = -10
sprite_y = 360


# Основной игровой цикл
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            try:
                sys.exit
            finally:
                main = False

        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord("a"):
                player.control(-steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord("d"):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord("w"):
                print("jump")
                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord("a"):
                player.control(steps, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord("d"):
                player.control(-steps, 0)
               
            if event.key == ord("q"):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False

    # Рисуем фон
    world.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

    # Рисуем спрайт
    player.update()
    player_list.draw(world)

        # Обновляем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Ограничиваем количество кадров в секунду
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)


Обработайте условие отдельно. Например можете добавить if в цикл

Я не особо понял, как это сделать? я занимаюсь pygame 2 дня

Этот вопрос не относится к pygame, это просто python, если у вас нет опыта в программировании, стоит начать с изучения языка

Мне поможет в изучении языка , если вы поможете мне сами. По мимо PyGame я и развиваю Python, но пока уклад даю книге по созданию 1 игры на pygame , подаренной мне моему дедушкой. Если вы мне объясните и поможете решить проблему , я буду благодарен и буду понимать в чем была ошибка.

Можем вместе разобраться. Для начала, вы говорите, у вас есть файлы Sto, sto1, sto2, sto3. Сколько у вас всего файлов? И откуда взялась цифра 5?

Спасибо за то что отозвались, я благодарен вам. Всего файлов с названием sto у меня 4. Sto, sto1, sto2, sto3. Если считать все файлы анимаций (с мечом, бегом, ударом мечоми т.д.) , у меня их 17. Изначально я писал туда вместо 5, 4, но позже мне сказали , что это неверно и нужно , что-бы стояла 5. Я так понял уже, что я делал все верно и ставил правильно 4 , а не 5?

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

newtonioapple, никто вам не говорил что надо 5, я просто уточнил у вас, почему 4, а не 5. Мне кажется вы не правильно даете имена файлам. Попробуйте назвать их  sto1.png, sto2.png, sto3.png, sto4.png , а цикл от 1 до 5.

Я не говорил про вас, не только вы мне так говорили. А так спасибо за совет.
